# Foundation For Apps, Angular, Display data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, controller, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for Apps, which contains parts of AngularJS. I'm trying to render the content of a local JSON file by accessing it through a controller, and then rendering the results into 'cards'. Ideally, the data set is also searchable.

Right now I've simply implemented a page: 
    ---
    name: results
    url: /results
    controller: ProvidersCtrl
    ---

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-block">
        <div ng-model="providers" class="grid-content">
            {{providers}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this code in controllers.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('application',[]);

App.controller('ProvidersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('providers.json')
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.providers = res.data;
    });
});
```

Here is my index.html's head section:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="application">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Provider Directory</title>
    <link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm sure it's just a misunderstanding of angular and data.

Referentially here is my JSON data (a sample).

```
[
  {
    "specialty": "Cardiovascular Disease",
    "registered": "Sunday, January 25, 2015 5:37 AM",
    "about": "Enim sint dolor sint ad ad proident eiusmod amet et laborum. Commodo esse cupidatat aute do non elit sunt incididunt id cillum eu cupidatat aliquip. Labore id culpa esse qui incididunt pariatur veniam ea ex occaecat anim dolor.\r\n",
    "address": "148 Metropolitan Avenue, Dyckesville, California, 9414",
    "fax": "+1 (844) 572-2968",
    "phone": "+1 (893) 544-2135",
    "email": "gilliam.rosales@fuelton.biz",
    "company": "FUELTON",
    "last_name": "Rosales",
    "first_name": "Gilliam",
    "guid": "aeeb1cb4-92b1-43d2-af9d-8735ab791ea7",
    "index": 0,
    "_id": "55595e5258a89e4168d46cdf"
  },
  {
    "specialty": "Urology",
    "registered": "Friday, November 21, 2014 8:24 AM",
    "about": "Lorem occaecat qui officia duis ad Lorem fugiat ex mollit eiusmod laborum et sit. Laboris proident proident quis aliquip mollit dolor laborum anim aute dolor aliqua irure. Qui sint sit exercitation esse fugiat magna amet amet ut elit elit. Non magna ea dolore aliqua esse qui. Irure elit cupidatat enim cillum dolore. Adipisicing irure sunt sint dolor laboris do. Cillum magna excepteur est nulla nisi id exercitation id officia quis aliqua.\r\n",
    "address": "501 Marconi Place, Shindler, Utah, 1246",
    "fax": "+1 (823) 424-3183",
    "phone": "+1 (976) 574-3689",
    "email": "dickson.flynn@eclipto.tv",
    "company": "ECLIPTO",
    "last_name": "Flynn",
    "first_name": "Dickson",
    "guid": "55189c5b-b0ff-403a-9e54-2db2350fb5d6",
    "index": 1,
    "_id": "55595e529c0a3722914b713a"
  }
```

---

Edit: Here is what I'm seeing in Dev Tools: 
Edit 2: Removed the dev tools, those were fixed when I moved the controller to app.js
Also made minor correction to json, removing the `providers = '` from the beginning.

Still not displaying anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer :

```
var myApp = angular.module('application',[]);

myApp.controller('ProvidersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('providers.json')
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.providers = res;
    });
});
```

For Template:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-block">
        <div ng-model="providers" ng-repeat="(key, value) in providers" class="grid-content">
            <span>{{key}} : </span><span>{{value}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick catch, it didn't work. I'm going to add my error messages to my question, hopefully that will help.

Comment: Could you please verify here : http://pro.jsonlint.com/ , if your json is correct.

Comment: verified, i had to remove the providers = ' from the beginning, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had A TON of stuff incorrect, borrowing from here and there and everywhere, and here is the final result:

app.js controller =

```
var myApp = angular.module('application');
myApp.controller('ProvidersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/providers.json').then(function(res){
      $scope.providers = res.data;
    });
  });
```

Notes: 
(1) The `var myApp` needed to be `angular.module('application');` because that is how foundation for apps names it in the previous lines of app.js. I put providers.json in the root directory, for simplicity sake. I eliminated the controllers.js file and just put the code in app.js.

results.html =

```
---
name: results
url: /results
---
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-block">
        <div class="grid-content">
            <div ng-controller="ProvidersCtrl">
              {{ providers }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(1) I used ng-controller, and not ng-model, to bind the data to the div. 
(2) I eliminated the use of the foundation for apps convention of spec'ing the controller in the header.